# Assign array key's value to another key of the same array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

When creating an array, is there any way I could assign a key's value to another key in the same array?

For example:

```
<?php
$foobarr = array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => $foobarr[0] . 'bar',
);
?>
```

In this example `$foobarr[1]` holds the value 'bar'.

Any way I can do this so that `$foobarr[1] == 'foobar'`?

Comment: question is, why do you need to do it that way?

Comment: not like that no - the statement on the right of `=` is evaluated before it is assigned to `$foobarr` so within the array construct `$foobarr` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: What @MarkoD said.  What's the problem that you're trying to solve?  There's probably a way to solve it without this particular technical trick, which doesn't work in PHP.

Comment: @NappingRabbit of course it doesn't work, and final comma in array is not a problem

Comment: `$foobarr[] = "foo"; $foobarr[] = $foobarr[0]."bar";`

Comment: @jdstankosky comments must not be used to provide resolving advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you assign the keys individually:

```
$foobarr = array();
$foobarr[0] = 'foo';
$foobarr[1] = $foobarr[0] . 'bar';
```

etc.  But not all at once inside the initializer - the array doesn't exist yet in there.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that, because the array hasn't been constructed yet when you try to reference it with `$foobarr[0]`.

You could save `'foo'` to another variable though, and just use that:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$foobarr = array (
    0 => $foo,
    1 => $foo . 'bar',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you'd need to reference it outside though.

```
$foobarr = array (
    0 => 'foo'
);
$foobarr[1] = $foobarr[0] . 'bar';
```